# Please tell me what "count with" means

Tags: idioms, interpretation

Among the lyrics, there is the sentence "you can count me with the dreamers."

This phrase is from movie called Tangled. It's the lyrics from "I've got a dream".

What exactly does that mean?

count A with B?  is that right?

regard or include?

How should I interpret it?

Comment: Did you try looking it up? What did you find?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can understand it so:
"you can count me with the dreamers." = "you can think about me that I'm a dreamer."
"you can count me with the dreamers." = "you can think about me that I'm one of the dreamers."

Comment: For what it's worth, there are currently two answers with more votes than this one that I consider worse than this one, because they don't actually say what "count me with the dreamers" means. Though I agree it's clear you don't speak English natively, you at least answered the question correctly; that's enough for me.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: But I think the question here is about the expression "count me with", not "the dreamers" since that could be replaced by any other group.  And besides, we can't really know what "the dreamers" means without the having the context of the movie.

Comment: "You can think about me that" is a really unusual phrasing. "You can consider me [to be] one of the dreamers", "You can consider me [to be] a dreamer" or "You can think of me as a dreamer" sounds more natural to me.

Comment: @jamesqf, in context, "the dreamers" means "people who have a cherished ambition or desire" - in the case of the person [speaking that particular line,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTuwo_TqlhQ) the desire to become a concert pianist.  But that isn't what the OP is asking anyway.

Comment: @Harry Johnston: Yes, as I said, if you have the context of the movie you will probably know what "the dreamers" means there.  But since I don't, I could only guess.

Comment: @jamesqf, I don't think that's what Daniel was getting at though.  I don't mean to criticize your answer, as it does correctly explain the meaning ("the speaker is one of the named group") but this one seems likely to be easier for a non-native speaker to understand.  (Though as the entire thread started with a now-deleted criticism of sayfriend for answering, I suppose it's all moot anyway!)

Answer (score 25):

An alternative phrasing would be "you can number me among".  That is, the speaker is one of the named group, with the (often rhetorical, as here) implication that a large number of people or things is being divided into separate, mutually exclusive groups, and being counted.  E.g. "Senator X is counted with Trump's supporters".

Comment: 'A is/was numbered among the Bs' is also a quite common way of saying it.

Answer (score 13):

It is definition 4 [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/count?s=t): "to include in a reckoning; take into account"

Answer (score 10):

It means precisely "When you count the dreamers, you have my permission to include me."

Answer (score 2):

It is the opposite of what people mean when they say “count me out” or “I don’t count”.